Ideal $ \langle x_1^2 - x_1 , \ldots , x_n^2 - x_n \rangle $ radical?
Consider the ideal generated by the Boolean constraints
$$
P = \langle x_1^2 - x_1 , \ldots , x_n^2 - x_n \rangle.
$$
Is $P$ a radical ideal?
A few attempts. The above statement is supposed to be true but I can't see why.
Attempt: Consider a polynomial $q = \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha} x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ is a multi-index, $c_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^{\alpha} = x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot \dots \cdot x_n^{\alpha_n}$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Assume that $q^k \in P$, then we have the identity
$$
q^k = \left( \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha} x^{\alpha} \right)^k = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i(x)(x_i^2 - x_i)
$$
for some $h_1(x), \ldots, h_n(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. My objective is showing that there exist $l_1(x), \ldots, l_n(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ such that
$$
q = \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha} x^{\alpha} = \sum_{i=1}^n l_i(x)(x_i^2 - x_i).
$$

What have you tried?

Added an attempt. It's only a statement of definitions, but this is the best I got so far and I'm struggling to move forward.

Can you prove it when $n=1$?  Could you use tensor products to reduce to this case?

Are you familiar with the characterization of radical ideals in terms of the corresponding quotient? I think that's the easiest way to do this.

We have that $$\sqrt{P}=\bigcap_{P\subseteq\mathfrak p}\mathfrak p$$ the intersection of all prime ideals that contain it. For a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ to contain $P$ we must have $x_i(x_i-1)\in\mathfrak p$ for each $i$. So either $x_i$ or $x_i-1$ is in each $\mathfrak p$. So $$I_\varepsilon=(x_1-\varepsilon_1,x_2-\varepsilon_2,\ldots,x_n-\varepsilon_n)\subseteq\mathfrak p$$ where $\varepsilon_i=0,1$. $I_\varepsilon$ is a maximal ideal, since $\Bbb R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I_\varepsilon\cong\Bbb R$. We then have $$\sqrt{P}=\bigcap_{\varepsilon}I_\varepsilon=(x_1(x_1-1),\ldots,x_n(x_n-1))=P$$
